# Case insensitive enum mongoose/mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, enums

In my user.js model, user schema is as below:

```
let gender = {
    values: ['male', 'female'],
    message: '`{VALUE}` is not a valid gender.'
};

let userSchema = new Schema({
    "gender": {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        enum: gender,
        required: [true, 'Please tell your gender.']
    }
});
```

Now while creating a new user if user passes **male** as gender document is created successfully. However in case of **Male, MALE** it fails.
How can make it case insensitive?

I don't feel below solution is rigid, there must be some better way of doing. Please help.

```
let gender = {
    values: ['male', 'female', 'Male', 'Female', 'MALE', 'FEMALE'],
    message: '`{VALUE}` is not a valid gender.'
};
```

Comment: How are you setting the user before saving? Can't you make it lowercase before setting it? Also is the data coming from a form?

Comment: I agree, but that is my last option to go with. I want to avoid manual manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom validator that compares the toLowerCase() version of the string with the set defined in your enum.

```
userSchema.path('gender').validate((genderValue) => {
    let genders = ["male", "female"]
    return genders.includes(genderValue.toLowerCase())
}, 'Invalid gender')
```